# How to get a time visible in events?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar 1.5.3 to display events from a json feed. I have 4 fields per event fed back - id, start, end and title. This works with each event block displaying the title.
In the FullCalendar examples the events with start and end dates show with a start time inserted before the title (formatted as 7p or 10:30a for example). How is this achieved? All my events have start and end times and I'm using the following settings...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#claimCalendar').fullCalendar({
        theme : true,
        editable : false,
        firstDay : 1,
        aspectRatio : 4,
        timeFormat: {
            '' : 'H(:mm)t'
        },
        allDayDefault: false,
        eventSources: [
            { //list of my eventSources
            }
        ],
        loading: function (bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('loading').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how to get the time to display? Eventually I would like the following information displayed for each event

> start title end  e.g. 00:00 *title* 07:30

Comment: look at [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/), and even maybe the [Javascript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Thanks Giorgio, but I have specified my timeFormat as shown above. I even tried just - timeFormat: 'H(:mm)t' and timeFormat: { month:'H(:mm)t'} and still no luck.

Comment: what is your output now anyway? and have is allDay or allDayDefault set to false?

Comment: my output comes from a json feed. Each event always has a start and end date. The data represents claims for work done so my feed brings a numeric id, a start datetime and end datetime and a title. I have allDayDefault set to false and for good measure I have set allDay to false in my events params. I'm only using month view. The events all display in the right order (newest at the top of the cell, oldest at bottom). But all that displays is the title. As I mentioned I'd like to eventually end up displaying start title end, but for the time being would be happy with just start title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sorted this out... Not sure why this has happened as I have used both allDayDefault:false in the fullCalendar params and allDay:false in my events but no time was displayed. I then modifed line 38 in FullCalendar.js 1.5.3 from allDayDefault:true to allDayDefault:false and hey presto I got my times showing.

I've also solved my second task and my events now display start - title - end.

Comment: Just wondering, were you using the minified or uncompressed version? as I did a compare on the `fullcalander.min.js` linked on their demo page and the one that downloads as part of the package. From what I believe, if you use the Minified version, this issue shouldn't arise!

Comment: I was using the uncompressed version as I have made some additional modification. My calendar is being used to display monthly claims. As our claim month begins on the 24th of each month I had to do some modifications so that the calender showed the 24th in the first row and end on the 23rd of the following month in row 5/6 with dates outside this greyed out. The event as the individual claims for overtime, telephone standby and call-outs.

Comment: Continuing... These are three json feeds so that I can colour them in different colours. I have also limited the feed so that it only displays the claims that are valid for that claim month, in other words there are no events shown on greyed out days even though there may well be claims for those days. They will only show when the calendar claim month is changed and they become active days.